# Where's the best place to get good staffs?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

I was wondering where's the best place to get good staffs for wizards in the game "Realm of the Mad God", because I'm level 20 and I have a T3 staff.  I didn't get any good staffs, and I really want to get one. I tried to sell some good things I got, like a T11 helm, but no one wanted. I tried in a lot of servers, and I didn't get anything good for wizards.

Comment: Trading for items is a good way to get items you want, farm in the godlands until you find a good staff or get a good tradable item. Btw, there is no such thing as a T11 helm.

Comment: that is such a t11 helm, but i just died yesterday trying to sell it at the place of the abyss with 20 guys in there. Well, at last i got 256 fame :P

Comment: No, the helms only go up to T6 I think you mean sword or armour. Also, the best place to trade is in the nexus of USWest.

Answer (score 2):

Finding good weapons can be tricky.  Most older players have huge stashes so that they don't have to spend time hunting for equipment or trading for it.  If you want an item and don't have it, there are three ways to get it:

1. Buy it in the Nexus for actual money (Gold).  This isn't a good idea, *ever*, since Gold should only be spent on the stuff that is Gold-exclusive (character slots, vault chests, and dye/cloths).
2. Find it through playing.  If you want a decent weapon, you can get it by slaying monsters which drop equipment.  The Godlands (a grey area in the center of the map) have powerful creatures which drop equipment, stat potions, and pet eggs.  In particular, Red Demons and Cyclops Gods (quests that will show up on your minimap) spawn with chests on the ground near them.  T7 weapons - including staves - will often be found there.  Another way to get equipment is to find an Undead Lair, a portal to a dungeon that drops from Ghost Gods when they die.  Killing monsters in here will often drop equipment.
3. Trade for it.  In RotMG, stat potions are used as currency.  The lowest-value ones are generally agreed to be potions of Speed or Dexterity, so if you have one of these, you can find someone who will trade you a t8 staff for one.  If you don't have any potions (or "pots", as they're called), you can trade equipment - a tier four or five ability item will be worth a tier 8 or 9 weapon.  If you want to find people who are trading their items, check on [Realmeye](http://www.realmeye.com/offers-to/sell/2719), a site where people buy and sell in-game items.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get a tier 6 staff in the godlands by a pink bag. If you want a better staff than tier 6, you can do 18 percent or more damage to a god and sometimes get a soulbound loot which have really good stuff like staffs. You can also run dungeons and get really good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You should just go to Oryx, and kill him, and find white bags and find ur weapon.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can see full list of places "where to get this staff" here: https://www.realmeye.com/wiki/staves (just click on any staff name).

Second, the order for you to progress should be following:

1. Once you reached level 20 you need to go into [godlands](https://www.realmeye.com/wiki/mountains): find the biggest group of people in the centre of the map and tp to them. Keep your distance from the gods and kill them (I understood you play wizzard). There you can find t7-t8 staffs, which are much better than t3, in an hour. But be carefull and keep your finger on nexus hotkey if you have never been there before.
2. Then you can do medium level [dungeons](https://www.realmeye.com/wiki/dungeons) where you can get t11 staff, which is more than enough. The easiest to farm is Cemetery. This will take some time, more than one hour, unless you are lucky.
3. There are dungeons and Oryx castle to get t12 weapon, but don't even think about them once you can perform items 1 and 2 easily.

Third, when you get a good weapon, but not the one you need you can trade it for good staff. This will make it muck faster. I recommend realmeye for this: https://www.realmeye.com/current-offers . There you can see how much people want and how much they give for an item you found, and you can chose appropriate price for yourself. You login and live the offer and people contact you ingame. Or you can contact them if you like someones offer.

Also [this guide](http://bluenosersguide.weebly.com) could be quite useful to put all things together in your head.

Answer (score -1):

Wait for Oryx's castle, get as close as you can to [Oryx](http://realmofthemadgod.wikia.com/wiki/Oryx_the_Mad_God), and spam that spell of yours.  You should be surprised by what you can get if you do that enough times.

Comment: I would not recommend doing this. You can easily die in Oryx's Castle even as an 8/8 and you need good DPS to qualify for loot.